# mongoDB aggregate mergeObjects

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Here is my collection structure, tried $mergeObjects,
but did not know how to use in right way, please help

```
{
    _id: ObjectId('60a5531cd6186f39b42d4344'),
    comments: [
        {
            comment: "test1",
            client_id: "1111"
        },
        {
            comment: "test2",
            client_id: "1111"
        },
        {
            comment: "test3",
            client_id: "3333"
        }
    ],
    clients: [
        {
            client_id: "1111",
            name: "name 1111"
        },
        {
            client_id: "3333",
            name: "name 3333"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want an aggregate query which merges the two documents

This is the expected output

```
{
    _id: ObjectId('60a5531cd6186f39b42d4344'),
    comments: [
        {
            comment: "test1",
            client_id: "1111",
            name: "name 1111"
        },
        {
            comment: "test2",
            client_id: "1111",
            name: "name 1111"
        },
        {
            comment: "test3",
            client_id: "3333",
            name: "name 3333"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

- `$unwind` to deconstruct the array
- `$addFields` or $project can be used
- `$map` to go through the array and select necessary field
- `$mergeObject` to merge the name with the comments array
- `$filter` to filter the array based on the condition

Here is the code

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      comments: {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$comments",
          "as": "first",
          "in": {
            "$mergeObjects": [
              "$$first",
              {
                $arrayElemAt: [
                  {
                    $map: {
                      input: {
                        $filter: {
                          input: "$clients",
                          as: "second",
                          cond: {
                            $eq: [
                              "$$first.client_id",
                              "$$second.client_id"
                            ]
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      in: {
                        name: "$$this.name"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  0
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yyhOrWO9-cW)**